# use keyof in a mapped type to return an array of values in typescript

Tags: typescript

In typescript I can create a type safe array of object keys like this:

```js
export type Keys<T> = [keyof T][];

export const keys = <T>(o: T): Keys<T> => Object.keys(o) as any;

const k = keys(a);
```

But how could I create a similar type for the values:

```js
export type Values<T> = [T][keyof T];

// Type 'keyof T' cannot be used to index type '[T]'.
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `Array<T>` ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to index into `T`, not `[T]`:

```
type Values<T> = T[keyof T][]; // or Array<T[keyof T]>

type Foo = { a: number, b: string };

type FooValues = Values<Foo>; // (string | number)[]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM4B4AqA+KBeKTAbQGsIQB7AM0IF0jaBuAKGdEigDEKL8oBvKHABcUAHZIAtgCMIAJwA0UaaNTA5ASzEBzKAF8WbcNG4V4yNH3MoMp7IygB6R1AAUazTqgAfcVNlyAJQMQA)

---

`[T]` is tuple with single `T` element, so your original attempt is trying to "index into" tuple using `T`'s keys - hence the error.